# SQL Query to Get the Nearest Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a really complex query. I have two tables as below.

Table 1

```
EmployeeId Status DateA

   A        BIL   1/1
   A        BON   2/1
   A        BIL   2/1 
   A        BIL   3/1 
   A        BIL   4/1 
   A        BIL   5/1
   A        BIL   6/1
```

**Table 2:**

```
Employee ID  Reason ExDate   DateB

   A          IN   1/1     
   A          OUT  4/15       **4/1**
   A          IN   6/1
   A          OUT  8/15       **9/1**
```

So , the problem is. I want to update the DateB Column in Table 2 with the Value from Date A from Table 1. The condition for that are

1. Reason column in Table 1 = BIL
2. I want to pick that date from Date A column which is the closest ( 30 Days interval) to ExDate with Reason column value = 'OUT'

I am primarily stuck with the 2nd Statement.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you dates actually stored in that format?

Comment: Try using the DateAdd() function to get your 30 day interval (http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_dateadd.asp)

Comment: No thats' for the example..my dates are in the Date Format

Comment: What's the logic, why does 4/15 go to 4/1, and 8/15 to 9/1?

Comment: The logic is I am trying to get the nearest date to the 4/15 date in Table 1 and that is 4/1 and similarly for 8/15 the nearest is 9/1

Answer (score 2):

Is this MS-SQL 2005 or later?  If so, try:

```
select * 
from table2 t2 cross apply (select top 1 dateA from table1 where status = 'BIL' order by abs(datediff(d, dateA, exDate))) t1
```

If that looks right, then you can:

```
UPDATE t2 SET DateB = t1.DateA
from table2 t2 cross apply (...
```